# Building projects with cuFFT callbacks and C++11 using CMake

Tags: c++11, cuda, cmake, cufft

Building a CUDA 8.0 project with cuFFT callbacks requires using the statically linked cuFFT library and compile the code as relocatable device code using (-dc compiler option). I've been unable to make this happen with CMake v3.7.0 using CUFFT_STATIC_LIBRARY, etc.. Anyone been able to build such a project with CMake?

Relevant expressions in my project CMakeLists.txt for the dynamically linked cuFFT library:

```
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
list(APPEND CUDA_DEV_LIBRARIES
            ${CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY})

set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} --std=c++11")

cuda_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_SRCS})

link_directories(${CUDA_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_DEV_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: What exactly makes you unable to build it. Do you get errors or something?

Comment: Tried a lot of different things, got a lot of different errors during the build. A common one was that nvcc complained about the `--std=c++11` flag, but it's needed for compilation. I'm hoping that someone can cut & paste a working CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I've figured out the `c++11` part. Usually I won't add this option since cmake will add it automatically. And your manually adding option will conflict with the cmake one. However, the static linking is troublesome. Now I guess maybe it has to run cmake `COMMAND` from scratch...

Comment: In general, you should prefer to let CMake sort out what flags to use to enable C++11 rather than modifying `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, etc. directly. You do this with the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` and `CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS` variables. For a full discussion of this topic, see [this article](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/). It's possible though that this might not work reliably for some cross-compiling arrangements, so give it a try and see if it has been fully implemented for nvcc.

Comment: Tried following the directions in the linked article and was rewarded with: `error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.` This was also after adding `set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)`. I'm digging around to see if there's a solution beyond manually adding the c++11 compiler flag as in my sample code.

Comment: New documentation changes due for CMake 3.8.0 add target properties for CUDA_STANDARD and friends. Merge request for the docs changes [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/319), but not sure if the target properties exist already and can be used with earlier versions. There's at least [one other merge request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/308) which implements related functionality for the new properties which is also due for 3.8.0.